# Using JSON with sprite kit to set up a player who can level up

Tags: json, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode

I am new to swift/spritekit, i was asked by my 8 year old to make him a basic game so i said yes (almost regretting it now lol)

What i am trying to achieve: a character who has the ability to "level up" based off experience points earned - I am using a JSON file to describe the levels

JSON file:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "spriteTexture": "playerL1",
        "weapon": "playerL1Weapon",
        "expToLvlUp": 50,
        "health": 2,
        "attack": 1,
        "defense": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "spriteTexture": "playerL2",
        "weapon": "playerL2Weapon",
        "expToLvlUp": 60,
        "health": 7,
        "attack": 2,
        "defense": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "spriteTexture": "playerL3",
        "weapon": "playerL3Weapon",
        "expToLvlUp": 100,
        "health": 10,
        "attack": 5,
        "defense": 5,
    }
]
```

Decodable file:

```swift
import Foundation


extension Bundle{
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ Type: T.Type, from file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle")
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else{
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle")
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode /(file) from bundle")
        }
        
        return loaded
    }
}
```

I have set up a struct to get the values from the JSON file:

```swift
import SpriteKit

struct PlayerLevel: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let spriteTexture: String
    let weapon: String
    let expToLvlUp: Int
    let health: Int
    let attack: Int
    let defense: Int
}
```

and here is my class:

```swift
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    var type: PlayerLevel
    {
        didSet{
            levelUp()
        }
    }
    
    init(type: PlayerLevel){
        self.type = type
        
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type.spriteTexture)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: texture.size())

        position.x = -900
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionType.player.rawValue
        physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionType.enemy.rawValue | CollisionType.enemyWeapon.rawValue
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionType.enemy.rawValue | CollisionType.enemyWeapon.rawValue
        zPosition = 5
        name = "player"
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func shoot(){
        let shot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: type.weapon)
        shot.name = self.type.weapon
        shot.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        shot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: shot.size)
        shot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionType.playerWeapon.rawValue
        shot.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionType.enemy.rawValue | CollisionType.enemyWeapon.rawValue
        shot.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionType.enemy.rawValue | CollisionType.enemyWeapon.rawValue

        addChild(shot)
        shot.zPosition = 3

        shot.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        let movement = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 4000, y: shot.position.y), duration: 1)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([movement, .removeFromParent()])
        shot.run(sequence)
    }
    func levelUp(){
        self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type.spriteTexture)
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type.spriteTexture)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
    }
}
```

Firstly, i'm wondering if i have this set up the right way.
In my game scene:

```swift
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

enum CollisionType: UInt32 {
    case player = 1
    case playerWeapon = 2
    case enemy = 4
    case enemyWeapon = 8
    case ground = 16
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    // Properties
    var isPlayerAlive = true
    var playerLevels = Bundle.main.decode([PlayerLevel].self, from: "player-levels.json")
    let enemyTypes = Bundle.main.decode([EnemyType].self, from: "enemies.json")
    var currentEnemy = 0
    var currentLevel = 0 {
        didSet {
            player.type = playerLevels[currentLevel]
        }
    }
    var player: Player!
    var enemy: Enemy!
    var levelUp: SKSpriteNode!
    var healthLabel: SKLabelNode!

    var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode!
    let playerLevelLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    
    var score = 0 {
        didSet{
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
            
        }
    }
    let ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "groundBottom")
    let groundT = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gameGroundTop")
    var expLabel: SKLabelNode!
    var exp = 0 {
        didSet{
            expLabel.text = "Experience Points: \(exp) / \(playerLevels[currentLevel].expToLvlUp)"
        }
    }
    var health = 0 {
        didSet{
            healthLabel.text = "Health: \(playerLevels[currentLevel].health)"
        }
    }
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        makeGround()
        initializePlayer()
        spawnEnemy()
        makeScoreLabel()
        makeExpLabel()
        makeHealthLabel()
        
    }
    
    func initializePlayer(){
        player = Player(type: playerLevels[currentLevel])
        addChild(player)
        playerLevelLabel.text = "Details: \(player.type)"
        playerLevelLabel.fontSize = 40
        playerLevelLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.minY + 200)
    }
    func makeScoreLabel(){
        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.maxX - 250, y:self.frame.maxY - 100)
        scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .right
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 5
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
        scoreLabel.name = "score"
        addChild(scoreLabel)
    }
    func makeExpLabel(){
        expLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        expLabel.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.minX + 500, y:self.frame.maxY - 110)
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
        expLabel.zPosition = 5
        expLabel.text = "Expereience Points: 0 / \(playerLevels[currentLevel].expToLvlUp)"
        expLabel.name = "exp"
        addChild(expLabel)
    }
    func makeHealthLabel(){
    
        healthLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        healthLabel.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.minX + 1200, y:self.frame.maxY - 110)
        healthLabel.fontSize = 40
        healthLabel.zPosition = 5

        healthLabel.text = "Health: \(playerLevels[currentLevel].health)"
        healthLabel.name = "health"
        addChild(healthLabel)
    }
    func makeGround(){
        ground.name = "ground"
        ground.position.x = frame.midX
        ground.position.y = frame.minY
        ground.zPosition = 1
        addChild(ground)
        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: ground.texture!, size: ground.texture!.size())
        ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic  = false

        groundT.position.x = frame.midX
        groundT.position.y = ground.position.y + 50
        groundT.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        addChild(groundT)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.location(in: self)
        let nodesAtLocation = nodes(at: location!)
        for node in nodesAtLocation {
            if node.name == "score"{
                score += 10
                exp += 5
                
                upgrade()
            }
            if node.name == "attack"{
                attack()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func upgrade() {
        if exp < playerLevels[currentLevel].expToLvlUp { return }
        if currentLevel + 1 > playerLevels.count - 1 {
            gameOver()
            return
        }
        if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion") {
            explosion.position = player.position
            addChild(explosion)
        }
        //charLevelUp()
        
        currentLevel += 1
        playerLevelLabel.text = "Details: \(player.type)"
    }
    
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        guard let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node else { return }
        guard let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node else { return }
        
        let sortedNodes = [nodeA, nodeB].sorted { $0.name ?? "" < $1.name ?? ""}
        
        let firstNode = sortedNodes[0]
        let secondNode = sortedNodes[1]
        
        if firstNode.name == "ground" { return }
        if secondNode.name == "ground" { return }
        if secondNode.name == "player" {
            guard isPlayerAlive else { return }
            
            if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "explosion"){
                explosion.position = firstNode.position
                addChild(explosion)
            }
            
            //health -= 1
            
            if playerLevels[currentLevel].health == 0{
                gameOver()
                secondNode.removeFromParent()
            }
            firstNode.removeFromParent()
        } else if let enemy = firstNode as? Enemy {
            enemy.health -= 1
            
            if enemy.health == 0 {
                if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion") {
                    expLabel.position = enemy.position
                    addChild(explosion)
                }
                
                enemy.removeFromParent()
                score += 50
                exp  = enemy.expGive
            }
            if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion") {
                explosion.position = enemy.position
                addChild(explosion)
                
            }
            
            secondNode.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion") {
                explosion.position = secondNode.position
                addChild(explosion)
            }
            
            firstNode.removeFromParent()
            secondNode.removeFromParent()
        }
        
    }
```

I've managed to get the sprite to change texture and physics body, the expReq points to change based on the players level, however, I can't seem to update the health property or any of the others. Any help would be appreciated - I'm not sure if I have this set up correctly - please advise :)

Comment: Looks pretty well, maybe you're updating/overriding the label on some update, like when you get more exp or you get damage and you're not taking the new values. Doesn't looks like a problem with json especially if you can update other values. Have you and error con console?

Comment: Hey! No I don’t have any errors in my log. It updates the sprite texture but it doesn’t update the other properties, health attack etc. I may have figured it out though and will update this thread if I do. Thanks for your feedback :)